# Solr filter query for string

Tags: php, solr

I have been working with Solr recently to filter data using `set_filter_query`. I was able to work with Integer values.

```
$solr_dao->set_filter_query('ID:[3+TO+*]');
```

This query filters data having values 3 or more. I am also trying to include a word search on a field using

```
$solr_dao->set_filter_query('Comments:[*'.$search_term.'*]');
```

which doesn't seem to be working. This query should filter data with comments field having the search term. Any ideas what might cause this?

Answer (score 1):

use this instead :

```
$solr_dao->set_filter_query('Comments:*'.$search_term.'*');
```

Note that in Solr, it indexes every words. So if a row contains "Hello honey my name is John" in the column "foo", if your query is `foo:Hello World`, this row will satisfy the query, since Solr looks for words, and read spaces as "OR"...

Comment: I am also trying to include sorting on data based on number of occurences of the search term. Please suggest if you have any ideas.

Comment: @SnehaAvula Any new questions should be asked by themselves, and not in the comment section.

Comment: @SnehaAvula You should use facets or something like that, which is much more complex, to make a sort of "group by"... can't tell you more :)